# Can't reach meta.english.se after Chrome updated to v53 unless I manually remove the https part

Tags: support, ssl

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit version 1511 (OS Build 10585.545).

Recently my Chrome updated to version 53.0.2785.89 m (64-bit) and since then I get this error when entering [meta ELU.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

**NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**

[image]

[image]

I can access meta ELU.SE if I manually remove the "https" from it or click the button to *"proceed ... (unsafe)"*. But what's happening?

**EDIT:** The proposed duplicate is simply a part of more linked duplicates. I see that this problem has happened to many before me, but why did I start seeing this issue just after Chrome updated to version 53? I understand that SE's HTTPS setup isn't perfected yet, but how do I solve my problem for now?

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, that link takes me down a rabbit hole, a chain of "marked as duplicate", but no clear solutions.

Comment: Bottom line: HTTPS doesn't work on most Meta sites.

Comment: @Glorfindel But I had no such issues until Chrome updated to v53. Why is that?

Comment: You probably clicked the "proceed to..." link long ago and forgot about it, while Chrome remembered it - until that last update.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe so. But now I have to click it everytime I turn on the PC. I haven't found a good workaround for this yet. Also, Chrome updates very frequently and I don't remember seeing such an error in months.

Comment: So... just don't browse meta sites via https?? Problem solved.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have no other choice, apparently. Haha

Comment: Why? If you have plugin forcing https, disable it for stackexchange.com sub domains.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! Almost forgot that I have "HTTPS Everywhere" installed. Apparently the plugin has caused issues on many Chrome 53 users, says [Google results](https://www.google.co.in/search?&q=HTTPS+Everywhere+chrome+53).

Comment: So get rid of it... I'm not using plugins on permanent basis exactly for those reasons - I can't control the bugs and problems they cause to the browser. All in all, they cause more harm than good. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard YMMV. I have had the best experience with plugins ever since I started using Chrome years ago. The occasional hiccups are not gonna stop me from using plugins/extensions. :)

Comment: As you wish... just remember to accuse them first, before accusing SE. :-)