# The votes are showing up over post titles when I view a user's profile

Tags: support, bug

The votes are showing up over post titles when I view a user's profile

[image]

On windows 10 chrome with a 34 inch screen

Is it just me, but I seem to be experiencing every glitch++ on SE lately.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 and just relaunched the Chrome after it updated to  53.0.2785.101 m (wow, new tab style). i do not see this

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284233/cant-reach-meta-english-se-after-chrome-updated-to-v53-unless-i-manually-remove#comment921658_284233 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of my script [StickyVoteControls.user.js](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/StickyVoteControls.user.js), that you happen to have installed.

Apparently Stack Overflow had to go and give lots of things the `vote` CSS class.

Silly me for thinking classes actually meant something specific.

Fixed in the latest version, no need to panic, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not experiencing them on [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/310756/yvette) which I looked at just now from Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing it when I look at yours http://i.stack.imgur.com/PRpb1.png

Comment: erm it is because of a script I am using. Would you be able to delete this, so I can delete the question please?

Comment: @Yvette I think it is better for you to add an answer that explains what type of script caused the symptom that you are seeing.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the author has just updated the script, that was how I found out it was the script, I'm going to end up question banned on this site. I've made another blue.

Comment: @Yvette I think a question ban on anyone with 800+ rep would be very unlikely.

Comment: I have a lot of downvoted deleted questions. Anyway I asked the script author to post an answer

Comment: @Yvette I think it is always better to fix than delete questions.

Comment: it's hard when it's a no repro and not network related. Anyway the answer clears it up. Thanks for talking

Comment: @Yvette But other users could be using the same version of the same script, and if they find this post their problem will be solved.  That makes your post potentially useful.  I see that this question has downvotes, but it seems fine to me.

Comment: @snailplane thanks for that feedback